# cannot convert 'clist<int>::node*' to 'clist<char>::node*' in assignment

Tags: c++, templates, casting, circular-list

Here I'm making a `circular linked list ( template <class t> class clist; )` with a member function, `concat ()` used to concatenate one list at the end of the other. The problem lies in this function. Now when I'm concatenating two `clist` with same template parameters (let say both be `clist<int>`) then function works fine, but as soon as I try concatenate two `clists` ( `clist <int> c1` and `clist <char> c2`) then I need to do some casting in the function `concat`, and as I dont know much about templates, I cudnt actually figure out how to do that.

So the problem precisely is with the last second line of the program below. I have `clist <int> c1` whose member function `concat` is being called, and `clist <char> c2` which is being concatenated at the end of c1.

```
template <class t>
class clist
{
    struct node
    {
    t data;
    node* next;
    node (const t& x=0, node* nxt=0): data(x), next(nxt) { }
    };

    typedef node* NPTR;

    public:

    NPTR ptr;

    template <class r>
    void concat ( clist <r> & );

    // other functions like push, pop etc. to form the clist

    clist () : ptr(0) { }
};

template <class t>
template <class r>
void clist<t> :: concat ( clist <r>& c2 )
{
    // ptr is pointer to a certain node in the list through which the list is
    // accessedand is zero initially.

    if ( c2.ptr == 0 ) return;
    if ( ptr == 0 ) ptr = (NPTR) c2.ptr;
    else
    {
    NPTR p = ptr->next;
    ptr->next = (NPTR) c2.ptr->next;
    c2.ptr->next = ( ??? ) p ;
    ptr = (NPTR)c2.ptr;
}
```

Whatever I try it still shows the error `cannot convert 'clist<int>::node*' to 'clist<char>::node*' in assignment`.

Can somebody please tell what is the proper way of casting here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cast is actually saving you from making a heterogeneous list. What you seem to be trying to do is to concatenate two lists - one with int and one with char. Now conceptually that might seem reasonable but the structure of an int node and a char node are too different.

The only way this could make sense is if you copied the second list into a clist of ints and then concatenated.

Comment: But what if I need to make a heterogeneous list only! Isnt there any way to do that ?

Comment: yea, you're right. That list will anyway be a waste when I cant even access the members. But still is there a way to achieve it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Template arguments are not covariant nor contravariant; `clist<int>` and `clist<char>` are *completely different* types.  You cannot convert between them.  As the definition of the `node` type is contained within a template type, it is dependent on the template parameter as well, and the corresponding `node` types are similarly different.

Each list will only be able to contain one type.  If you are trying to write a list that can contain *any* type, you will need to use a variant-style type for the template argument.

Comment: The expression *covariant* is probably not the best one there. It is usually employed when talking about relations on types in inheritance relationships, where the relationship is *covariant* if it follows the same direction of inheritance, and *contravariant* if it follows the revers. Example: `struct A {}; struct B : A {}; struct base { virtual A* f(); }; struct derived : base { B* f(); };` the return types of `f` are *covariant*: the relationship between `A` and `B` varies in the same direction as the relationship between `base` and `derived`.

Comment: Nevertheless, template arguments are not covariant... nor are they contravariant.  You couldn't convert `Foo<derived>` to `Foo<base>` in that example, nor go in the other direction.  In this particular case, contravariance is probably the correct term -- while `int` is does not "derive" `char`, it is a wider type.